# xcode4 input sizes manually in interface builder

Tags: interface-builder, xcode4

So how can I make a button of 42px x 42px ?

Is there some panel to input the numbers manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the size in size inspector (an option in inspector window at right hand side).

Set height = 42; and width=42;